# Найти значения с тем же ключом в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `table` с полями `key` и `name`.
Ищу строки по значению `name`.
Хочу получить также строки в которых `key` совпадает с `key` из искомых.
Например:

```
KEY  NAME
1    ion
1    mari
2    antuan
3    delatri
4    demetrii
4    alex
5    potstdam
```

Запрос поиска по со значением `alex` выдавал результат:

```
KEY  NAME
4    demetrii
4    alex
```

Погуглив написал следующее, но выдаёт только 1 поле, без своего "дубля" по ключу:

```
SELECT `table`.* 
FROM `table` 
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT `name`, `key`
  FROM `table`
  GROUP BY `key`, `name`
  HAVING COUNT(*)>1) as `tbl`
ON
  `table`.`key`=`tbl`.`key` AND
  (`tbl`.`name` LIKE '%alex%')
WHERE `tbl`.`key` IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен обычный JOIN с этой же таблицей

```
select
  t2.*
from
  test t1
  JOIN test t2 ON (
    t1.`key` = t2.`key`
  )
where
  t1.`name` = 'alex'
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/GkAvCDmm9odkuths2Zpjm/1)

Comment: Я видимо мастер по усложнению себе жизни. Спасибо большое, да прибудет с вами сила :)

Comment: вас не смутило, что в вашем `db-fiddle` мой запрос?)

Comment: @Denis Форкал от вас. Забыл проапдейтить. Сейчас исправил

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, ищете такой способ?

```
select *
from `table`
where name = 'alex'
    or `key` = (select `key` from test where name = 'alex')
```

Пример на [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pPxEcAR3rYiSUCGHgycjLY/0).

Comment: О да. Это оно. Только сложность заключается в том, что это запрос поиска, и результатов запроса `Name` могут быть много, а на этот случай СУБД возвращает ошибку множественного результата.

Comment: @FriedrichBenderburg в таком случае `name = 'alex'` надо поменять на `name in ('alex', 'bober', 'not bober', ...)`, где в `in` у вас будут перечислены все имена.